# Regex: match up to character OR word with Google Sheets REGEXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I'm trying to extract a street address in Google Sheets.
In my data, the address is followed by either a comma(",") or the word "between"
Having trouble writing a REGEXTRACT function that matches up to the comma OR the word

This is as close as I've gotten:
`^(.*?)\s,|^(.*?)\sbetween`

Which works fine for addresses preceding commas, but not preceding 'between'

Is there a way to write this so it essentially says 'match up to the first instance of X OR the first instance of Y"?

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YjWKSa/1)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex pattern:

```
^(.*)?\s*(?:,|between)
```

This matches all content

- `^` from the start of the cell value
- `(.*)?` match and capture everything until the nearest
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `(?:,|between)` match `,` or the word `between`